# What is the best way to deploy code from a repo and Ansible?

Tags: git, deployment, ansible, devops

For our e-commerce website, I use the following deployment process with Ansible:

- Pull sources from the repository to the remote machine
- Symlink to this repository to `/var/www/mysite/current`
- Symlink of configurations files

But I'm not sure that's the best way to deploy the code as we can have the all repo in the remote with non needed files there.

So I was wondering if it would be better to:

- Pull the code in local (in a tmp for example)
- Make an archive and upload the archive to the remote directly in `/var/www/mysite/release/xxxxxxx`
- Symlink that release to current

What do you think? Is there a way to do that with Ansible?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't quiet understand what concerns you have with your current method. Why would you have "not needed files" in your repo? If they are not needed, remove them..

Comment: Let's say that I have a folder webroot and others folders with the deploy and compiles tools in my repo. If I pull the repo, this folders will be present in the remote machine too, when I just need the webroot and I cannot remove this folders from the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky question as to whether there can be a "best" answer without knowing all the intricacies of your deploy environment.  That being said, I would take a couple of things into consideration based on what you have said:

**Why is deploying the whole repo a problem?**

Are you storing large binary files that don't interact with your code in any way?  You might want to consider splitting them into another repository, or managing them in a different way (for instance, large disk images could be served by a build system rather than kept in git).  A submodule with these other components could also be a useful approach, since the repository can be cloned without pulling in the submodules, if so desired.

Or is the large history of the git repo causing the clone to be large?  In that case, you could do a shallow clone, which Ansible's git module supports.

**Archiving and copying**

This sounds like a solution that is more convoluted than it needs to be.

Presumably this would involve keeping a list of files that you want removed in your Ansible repo (increasing coupling of your Ansible code and target deployed repo), coordinate the local clone into a tempfile, remove the files, do the archive, do the remote transfer, do the remote unarchive.

This is contrasted with simply calling the Ansible `git` submodule.

I hate adding more complexity where it isn't needed.  I'd aim for the simplest approach.

Comment: You're right, the repo contains folders and files that should be split in another repos. I will clean it and keep just the webroot and deploy just the needed files. Thanks